# How can I comment count each thread, and echo the result?

Tags: php, mysql, count, comments

Hey I am knew to php/mysql and I want to know how to count the comments for each thread, and echo the number next to the thread.
Basically I am displaying 25 thread titles per page, and when you click on them, it takes you to a page where it is showing all the related comments. I was trying to simply count the comments "`comment_id`" that matched the "`id`" and echo them next to the titles, all in a while loop.
just let me know what information you need to help me and I will post it ASAP.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We would need to know the structures of the relevant tables to be able to give you a definite answer but the query should be something like this -

```
SELECT thread.id, thread.title, COUNT(comment.id) AS comment_count
FROM thread
LEFT JOIN comment
    ON thread.id = comment.thread_id
GROUP BY thread.id, thread.title
```

This is a rather crude example and I have not tried running it but it should be ok -

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


$sql = 'SELECT thread.id, thread.title, COUNT(comment.id) AS comment_count
    FROM thread
    LEFT JOIN comment
        ON thread.id = comment.thread_id
    GROUP BY thread.id, thread.title';

$results = $dbh->query($sql);

while ($row = $results->fetchObject()) {

    print "<a href=\"show_thread.php?thread_id={$thread->id}\">{$row->title} ({$row->comment_count})</a><br />\n";

}

?>
```

Comment: `$comment_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wall WHERE comment_id={$current_thread}");
while ($comment_result = mysql_fetch_array($comment_query)) {
  echo $comment_result[0];`
Is what ended up working for me, thanks for the help.